# Json response in Go(Gin) without escape characters

Tags: go

I have recently started working on Go APIs using GIN. My API is getting the data from DB with two columns where one column contains integer and other contains a json string.
The json string is dynamic and hence i cant use struct for that.
I am using `map[string]interface{}` to parse the json and modify it and then parse it back to json using `json.Marshal`. Now i am returning this json string as a response but getting escape characters. Have done some search regarding that, but didnt find any solution yet.
Here is the part of code that i am using

```
var interface_obj map[string]interface{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(grants.Data), &interface_obj)
grants_map := interface_obj["role_grants"].(map[string]interface{})
jsonString, err := json.Marshal(grants_map)
jsonBody := string(jsonString)
```

After this, I am returning this JSON as response in GIN framework like this

```
c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{"message": "Json retrieved successfully", "data": jsonBody})
```

But the output i am getting is

```
{
    "data": "[{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"project\"},{\"action\":\"all\",\"resource\":\"users\"},{\"action\":\"all\",\"resource\":\"roles\"},{\"action\":\"all\",\"resource\":\"project-settings\"},{\"action\":\"create\",\"resource\":\"single-entity-screening\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"single-entity-screening\"},{\"action\":\"create\",\"resource\":\"multi-batch-screening\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"multi-batch-screening\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"workspace\"},{\"action\":\"allocate\",\"resource\":\"workspace\"},{\"action\":\"update\",\"resource\":\"workspace\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"case\"},{\"action\":\"allocate\",\"resource\":\"case\"},{\"action\":\"review\",\"resource\":\"case\"},{\"action\":\"update\",\"resource\":\"case\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"report\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"audit-trail\"},{\"action\":\"read\",\"resource\":\"delivery\"}]",
    "message": "Grants retrieved successfully"
}
```

I printed it on my console and it looked fine there, but causing this issue on response.
Is there any way to resolve this using some standard way? Please guide
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do `json.Marshal(grants_map)`, just pass the value directly to `gin.H` and let `c.JSON` do the encoding, i.e.

```golang
gin.H{... "data": grants_map}
```

And in cases where you truly have raw JSON data at hand that you want to send as part of other not-yet-JSON data, you can wrap it into `json.RawMessage` to avoid the "double-encoding", i.e.

```golang
gin.H{... "data": json.RawMessage(jsonBody)}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Both of these solutions will cover my other use cases.
I have one more question. I am getting Json with indentation. Is there any way to return un-indented(In a single line) json with the solution to reduce the response data size? Just wanted to know for learning purpose.